# when I clicked checkbox inside a tableview the amount present inside one label should add to another label in iOS

Tags: ios

I have checkbox and label inside a tableview and when we click checkbox the price present in label in each cell of tableview should add to another label which is present in another view

```
@IBAction func checkUncheckButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {


    if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? PrepaidPageTableViewCell
    {

        let indexPath = tableviewOutlet.indexPath(for: cell)

        if cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.isSelected == false
        {

            cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checked_blue"), for: .normal)

            cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.isSelected = true

            viewHeightConstraint.constant  = 65

            cell.amountOutlet.text = "₹ "+amount_receivable_from_customerArray[indexPath!.row]

              isPrepaidOrder = false

            tableviewOutlet.reloadData()

        } else {

            cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unchecked_blue"), for: .normal)

            cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.isSelected = false

            self.viewHeightConstraint.constant = 0

            tableviewOutlet.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your cellfor row code

Comment: how would I paste it

Comment: checkbox also not working inside a tableview.actually when I click checkbox it should show the view and when I uncheck  the checkbox it should hide the view.it is is also not working

Comment: the amount which is present inside a label should add to another label when I click each checkbox inside a tableview

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PrepaidPageTableViewCell") as! PrepaidPageTableViewCell

    cell.customerNameOutlet.text = buyer_nameArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.deliverydateOutlet.text = "Delivery Date:\(dispatch_dateArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.amountOutlet.text = "₹\(amount_receivable_from_customerArray[indexPath.row])"

    cell.dispatchidoutlet.text = "Dispatch ID: \(id_dispatch_summaryArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.dispatchdateOutlet.text = "Dispatch Date:\(dispatch_dateArray[indexPath.row])"
    cell.checkUncheckButtonOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "unchecked_blue"), for: .normal)

    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```